# How to count Dynkin system for finite sets?

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

For a set of finite elements, is there a good way to list all of its Dynkin systems, please? I understand that all $\sigma$-algebras of a set are also Dynkin systems. Therefore, we should as many Dynkin systems as $\sigma$-algebras. My question is how many Dynkin systems can we have and how to find all the rest, please? Thank you!